# CRM user activity

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there a way to track user activity in Microsft Dynamics CRM? The end result would be a list of users, showing a datetime for each access into CRM, and possibly what modules are being accessed.

Also, is there a way to tie users to database connections, as is done in AX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? The reason I ask is because there are many different ways to log user access depening on purpose.

Detailed access logging can be performed by IIS (web log).
Logons are also tracked in  the Event Log->Security log.

Changes to entities can be tracked by implementing an audit log using workflows (or buying a [third party component](http://www.c360.com/Audit.aspx) to do this).

The third option is to write a .NET plugin that logs whatever you want on whatever event you want on the entities you choose. Lookup plugins in the [Microsoft CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/bb928212(en-us).aspx) for more information on how to do this.